# IIF or CASE in concatenation query

Tags: t-sql

I have the following query that is part of a Scalar Variable Function but I get the same result trying to run the query so it appears that the problem is in the concatenation and/or the use of a variable.

```
DECLARE @useCompTitle BIT
SET @useCompTitle = (SELECT z.useComplianceTitle FROM dbo.tblConfiguration z WHERE z.id = 1)
DECLARE @Output as VARCHAR(MAX) = '';
DECLARE @ReturnValue as VARCHAR(MAX)='';
SELECT @Output = @Output + 
                '<tr><td style="vertical-align:top">' + 
                p.ProcessNumber + 
                '</td><td>' + 
                (IIF(@useCompTitle = 0, p.Process, p.title)) + 
                '</td><td style="vertical-align:top">' + 
                CASE p.recordStatus 
                    WHEN 1 THEN N'Active' 
                    WHEN 2 THEN N'Inactive' 
                END  + 
                '</td></tr>'
FROM dbo.tblProcess p
CROSS JOIN dbo.Security_Compliance_Record_List(1, 0, 0) AS p1
INNER JOIN dbo.tblERLinkedRecords l ON p.id = l.recID
WHERE l.eventID = 1172 
AND l.linkType = 'C' 
AND p.id = p1.id 
AND p.recordStatus < 3
ORDER BY p.ProcessNumber
PRINT @OutputThe result should return multiple values in @Output but I am only getting the last record in the set.
```

I have also tried a CASE statement with the same result. If I replace the IIF (or CASE) with a simple field name I get the correct number of values.
The CASE for p.RecordStatus works correctly if the IIF is replaced by a simple field value (e.g. p.title).
We use the @useCompTitle process in many Stored Procedures but this is the first time in a concatenation query.

Comment: I have done some more testing. In the IIF, if I replace the field references with a variable (e.g. IIF(@useCompTitle = 0, 'Fred', 'Martha')) I get the correct number of values returned. Both the fields are defined as VARCHAR(MAX). I have tried using the CAST and CONVERT commands (to NVARCHAR) but that doesn't resolve the problem.

Comment: can you please show us your current output when you run your sql statement and what you expect to see

Comment: This is what I am expecting to see: <tr><td style="vertical-align:top">ABC88888</td><td>This is for Regulatory Compliance.</td><td style="vertical-align:top">Active</td></tr><tr><td style="vertical-align:top">ACC0005</td><td>Prudential Return</td><td style="vertical-align:top">Active</td></tr>

This is what I am getting:<tr><td style="vertical-align:top">ACC0005</td><td>Prudential Return</td><td style="vertical-align:top">Active</td></tr>

Comment: Obviously this is a join issue not iif or case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the input. After some more testing I found that the problem was in the ORDER BY and is a known [issue](https://marc.durdin.net/2015/07/concatenating-strings-in-sql-server-or-undefined-behaviour-by-design/). That is a great article. I resolved the problem by changing the Function to as per the suggestion and it all works correctly.

```
  CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CR_Events_Linked_Compliance]
```

(
    @parameter1 INT,
    @parameter2 BIT = 0,
    @recID INT,
    @useCompTitle BIT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Output as VARCHAR(MAX) = '';
    DECLARE @ReturnValue as VARCHAR(MAX)='';
    SELECT @Output = (SELECT '' + p.ProcessNumber + '' + IIF(@useCompTitle = 0, p.Process, p.title) + '' + IIF(p.recordStatus = 1, 'Active', 'Inactive') + ''
    FROM dbo.tblProcess p
    CROSS JOIN dbo.Security_Compliance_Record_List(@parameter1, @parameter2, 0) AS p1
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblERLinkedRecords l ON p.id = l.recID
    WHERE l.eventID = @recID AND l.linkType = 'C' AND p.id = p1.id AND p.recordStatus < 3
    ORDER BY p.ProcessNumber
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.','varchar(max)')
    IF @Output = ''
        SET @ReturnValue = ''
                Else
        SET @ReturnValue = '**Number****Process****Status**' + @Output + ''
    RETURN @ReturnValue 
END

Comment: you don't need a function...just need to join this table in your query. this is an overkill to be honest

Comment: I agree that it is overkill. The table is the primary FROM table (tblProcess). I tried adding an INNER JOIN to the same table with no success. I also tried switching the primary FROM table - again with no success.

Comment: if you got no success with joining the table probably you got the wrong type of join

Answer (score 0):

Using `IIF` and `CONCAT`

A demo

```
declare @mytable table (processnumber int, recordstatus smallint,process varchar(20), title varchar(20))

insert into @mytable 
values 
(1,1,'Proc1','Title1'),
(2,2,'Proc2','Title2'),
(3,1,'Proc3','Title3'),
(4,2,'Proc4','Title4'),
(5,1,'Proc5','Title5')



DECLARE @useCompTitle BIT
SET @useCompTitle = 1
DECLARE @Output as VARCHAR(MAX) = '';
DECLARE @ReturnValue as VARCHAR(MAX)='';

SELECT @Output = concat(@Output, 
                '<tr><td style="vertical-align:top">', 
                p.ProcessNumber,
                '</td><td>', 
                IIF(@useCompTitle = 0, p.Process, p.title),     -- as per @useCompTitle will always display Title when 1
                '</td><td style="vertical-align:top">',
                IIF( p.recordStatus  = 1,'Active','Inactive' ),
                '</td></tr>') 
from @mytable p


print  @Output
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Your sample works perfectly however it won't work in my code. `code`SELECT @Output = CONCAT(@Output, '<tr><td style="vertical-align:top">', p.ProcessNumber, '</td><td>', IIF(@useCompTitle = 0, p.Process, p.title), '</td><td style="vertical-align:top">', IIF(p.recordStatus = 1, 'Active', 'Inactive'), '</td></tr>')
FROM dbo.tblProcess p
CROSS JOIN dbo.Security_Compliance_Record_List(1, 0, 0) AS p1
INNER JOIN dbo.tblERLinkedRecords l ON p.id = l.recID
WHERE l.eventID = 1172 AND l.linkType = 'C' AND p.id = p1.id AND p.recordStatus < 3
ORDER BY p.ProcessNumber`code`

Comment: i think this is a join issue... check your join and make sure you are getting the right table joined

Answer (score -1):

If a query returns one row, then SQL Server stores that value in the variable. However, if there are multiple rows, that doesn't really make sense. A variable holds a single value, but there are multiple values to store in it. It could error out, but Microsoft chose to have it simply store the last value. It could have stored the first just as well, but that's not what they decided. In general, this isn't good behavior to rely on because it's not reasonable from a semantics perspective.

In fact, I think this is where you are getting caught up. While it's possible to think of a query has being a for loop over tables and rows, it's really not. It's a series of operations on sets of tuples (rows). Conceptually, the result is a single set of rows that "arrive" at one time. There's no order of execution of the rows (any more than there's an order of execution of an array just existing). Thus, there's no sense in this.

Now, what you want to achieve *is* itself reasonable. You want a string that is built by essentially concatenating the results of a query that returns multiple rows. Imagine you have a simpler query where you just want to sum up some numbers instead of concatenating strings. You would just use the `SUM()` aggregate, potentially with a `GROUP BY` clause. The result of that could be stored into a variable. Since the aggregation would make it so that only one row is in the result set, you don't have to worry about which row saves the value. String aggregation works the same way. Except...SQL Server didn't have a `STRING_SUM()` operation until SQL Server 2017. That said, there are still ways to do this in all versions of SQL Server. You can use an XML trick, or you can write your own custom aggregate function (in a .NET language). See [I need to write a query like group_concat in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44250601/i-need-to-write-a-query-like-group-concat-in-sql-server) for more on how to do this.

Hopefully this is enough to get you going!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of how SQL works. We use the '@Output = @Output +' quite a lot and so far it has served us well. With the investigation of this issue I have found the CONCAT command which appears to be more elegant, if not more efficient (it doesn't resolve the problem I am having). I have resolved the problem by adding another Function to return the required value.

Comment: @JamesO: if the `@Output = @Output +` trick has worked in the past, I wouldn't rely on it.